# Unable to execute file with superuser priviliges

Tags: permissions, software-installation, sudo, vmware, executable

I am trying to install the VMware client on my work computer, which is running CentOS 7 and on which I have superuser privileges.

When I run the command

```
sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-5.2.0-14604769.x64.bundle
```

I get the following error message

```
sudo: unable to execute ./VMware-Horizon-Client-5.2.0-14604769.x64.bundle: Permission denied
```

When I run the same command without sudo the file executes, but the installer brings up a dialog box with the following error message

```
root access is required for the operations you have chosen.
```

I've checked the file's permissions, and I have execute privileges. I've even tried temporarily setting the privileges to 777, but it made no difference. Moving the file to another directory doesn't seem to help. I've run df and then mount to make sure noexec isn't set for this device, and it is not.

I've successfully installed programs on this computer before, so this behaviour seems particularly odd. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might get this to work or other ways I might try installing the VMware client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have NFS homes, and that the file is on a Kerberized NFS share, which means that even root can't read things in it. To work around it, as yourself (not root), copy the file to somewhere that isn't NFS (like /tmp), and then run it from there (or if /tmp is noexec, once it's there, copy it to somewhere else as root).

Comment: I wasn't able to execute the file after moving to /tmp, so I tried moving it with root, and it doesn't seem to see the file, producing an error message
`mv: cannot stat ‘VMware-Horizon-Client-5.2.0-14604769.x64.bundle’: No such file or directory`

I tried moving it back as myself, and it succeeded. As a test, I tried moving it back to /tmp as root, and again it couldn't see it.

Comment: @AllanMcPherson Like I said, /tmp is probably noexec. Once you move it there, move it to somewhere that isn't noexec (like /root) as root. (And then double-check the permissions as a sanity test.)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. That worked.